# Swift Update Latitude and Longitude

Tags: swift, dictionary, location

I want to extract and update the latitude and longitude every time I press the button and to show where the user is in an initial location, its very important to update the location becauses it is a nearby app, here is my code :

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


@IBAction func update(_ sender: Any) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()



    let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(latitude),\(longitude)radius=5000&types=gas_station&key=AIzaSyDVyaidSrF37d0M6XrHvosTXK4z-rkoLDg")!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]

    let latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude

    let longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05

    let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)


    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a CLLocationManager. At any time, you can get the device's location with

```
locationManager.location
```

which is a CLLocation. The one thing I would warn about, is that requestAuthorization, etc..., takes a few seconds, and that location will be nil until it's finished and the CLLocationManager has started locating. So be careful about unwrapping optionals, and consider creating your locationManager and requesting authorization, in a prior VC. A full IBAction, that gets your user's location, and inserts lat and long into the URL:

```
@IBAction func pushed(_ sender: Any) {
    if let location = locationManager.location {
          let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)radius=5000&types=gas_station&key=AIzaSyDVyaidSrF37d0M6XrHvosTXK4z-rkoLDg")!
          // Now do whatever you need to do with the URL, at this point
    }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but looks like the OP is already getting a location inside the did update location method. IMO he just wants to create an URL with that info when a button is pressed

Comment: how i implement it

Comment: I got the impression that he wants to get latitude and longitude, every time a button is pressed. @JuanJoseRodrigo: Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: i want to update the url with the new lat - long that the user has

Comment: I think I see. So you want: Button pressed -> get current location (lat and long) -> enter location in googleapi URL? I'll update my post.

Comment: Alright, done updating. That func I added takes the current location, and dumps the lat and long into the URL (which I copy-pasted from your original post).

Comment: The optional URL is unwrapped by the '!' at the end. Is that a problem?

Comment: @dylanthelion thanks i think thats correct, but it is giving me an optional value, how i change that?

Comment: @JuanJoseRodrigo you need to unwrap the optional location `if let location = locationManager.location,
    let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(location.coordinate.latitude),\(location.coordinate.longitude)radius=5000&types=gas_station&key=AIzaSyDVyaidSrF37d0M6XrHvosTXK4z-rkoLDg") {
    print(url)
}`

Comment: What @LeoDabus said. I usually force-unwrap ('let location = locationManager.location!'), because I want to know if my location manager isn't working, but if this is your first or second time using CoreLocation, I suggest Leo's method, as it will be safer. Also, I updated my post to include Leo's suggestion. Sorry about not unwrapping that in the first place.